# Fetch JSON data from server to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I would like to fetch JSON data from this server: 
http://eso.vse.cz/~xvojs03/studenti.json
to a table, but I do not know how to read Keys and Values and even the Array together to fetch them to the table.

This might be really stupid question but I am beginner in jQuery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>getJSON - tabulka studentů</title>
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://eso.vse.cz/~xvojs03/studenti.json")
          .done(function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
              $.each(data.predmety, function() {
                $("tr").append("<td>"
                  key + ": " + val + "</td><td>" + predmety.join(",") + " ")
              });
            });
          });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Následující JSON jsme získali Ajaxem ze serveru</h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Jméno</th>
          <th>Příjmení</th>
          <th>Stupeň</th>
          <th>Semestr</th>
          <th>Predměty</th>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code with giving a id for the table and putting this js snippet:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  $("#result-set").append("<tr><td>"+val.jmeno+"</td><td>"+val.prijmeni+"</td><td>"+val.stupen+"</td><td>"+val.semestr+"</td><td>"+val.predmety.join(",")+"</td></tr>");
});
```

Full page code would be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8" />    
<title>getJSON - tabulka studentů</title> 

<!-- bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<script>        
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON( "http://eso.vse.cz/~xvojs03/studenti.json" )
    .done(function(data){ 

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $("#result-set").append("<tr><td>"+val.jmeno+"</td><td>"+val.prijmeni+"</td><td>"+val.stupen+"</td><td>"+val.semestr+"</td><td>"+val.predmety.join(",")+"</td></tr>");
    });

  });
});
</script>    

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">        
    <h2>Následující JSON jsme získali Ajaxem ze serveru</h2>
    <table id="result-set">
      <tr>
        <th>Jméno</th>
        <th>Příjmení</th>
        <th>Stupeň</th>
        <th>Semestr</th> 
        <th>Predměty</th> 
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It still doesnt work, table is empty, can you try to check the code snippet again?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a syntax error in this line:

```
$("tr").append("<td>"key + ": " + val + "</td><td>" + predmety.join(",") + " ")
```

Insert a `+` between your `<td>` tag and the word `key` like so:

```
$("tr").append("<td>" + key + ": " + val + "</td><td>" + predmety.join(",") + " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The first fix was to add the reference to your blank table, as answered by @Juyal Ahmed.

Giving the table an id here:

```
<table id="result-set">
```

And then doing a query to look it up here:

```
$("#result-set").append
```

The problem I'm seeing now is a Cross-Origin  issue. Check out the console:

[output of the console showing CORS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlQ4D.png)